# Regexp to match multiline single or double quoted strings

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm building a Ruby script that read ruby sources files looking for calls to the function `_()` and grabing the strings of the parameter passed to it, which can be a multiline string, single or double quoted, for example:

1. Grab: `hello world`

   ```
   _('hello'+
   ' world')
   ```
2. Grab: `hello \nworld`

   ```
   _("hello \
   world")
   ```
3. Grab: `hello "world"`

   ```
   _("hello \"world\"")
   ```
4. Grab: `hello 'world'`

   ```
   _('hello \'world\'')
   ```

So I need a regexp to match and grab the string parameter. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry for the editing. Your original is good enough, but someone suggested an edit to your post which kind of merge into the edit without warning.

Comment: could you please be more precise? what you should not match, for example?

Comment: This looks more like a job for eval than for regex. I mean what, for example, if a variable was passed to `_()`? Regex certainly can't handle that.

Comment: What about calls like `_ %q{...}`? Or if someone uses a heredoc when calling `_`? I'd recommend grabbing gettext and seeing how it deals with `_` calls.

Comment: hello ProGNOMmers, I need to read ruby sources codes and match the parameter of the function _()

Comment: mu is too short, what is this %q{}, could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to analyze source code with regex usually leads to complex fragile code that doesn't work in all cases.  You would need to account for enclosing single and double quotes, here docs, quotes within the parentheses, etc.

What you probably need to do is get a ruby lexer.  There are several of these, some are written in ruby, some in antlr, probably even one in lex.  The lexer will parse the source into tokens, then you an scan the token list to find the pieces you want.

You might get some ideas about how to do this by looking at the ruby interpreter or at the syntax colouring code in an opensource editor.

An alternate way to do this is to write a regex that locates the interesting tokens, singe quote, double quote, _, (, ), and newline.  Then write a finite state machine that scans this list looking for the phrases of interest.  I've used this technique successfully for manipulating SQL.

What you haven't told us s what is the actual requirement.  There may be another solution that doesn't require any of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this instead of a regexp:

```
def _(str)
  str
end
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: hum, I need to extract calls from source codes, and evaluating all source code is not possible...